# Remap pause/break key

Tags: keyboard, remapping, windows-vista

I would like to remap a pause/break key into my dell inspiron 1545's keyboard, but all the utilities I've tried so far either haven't worked or don't support remapping of key "outside of the alphabet"

Sorry, I didn't make my post clear.

I don't have a pause/break key on my keyboard, but I need one for some of the programs I use (and no, I can't use +C or something to replace it)

I was hoping to be able to remap F12 to pause/break. If someone could write the AHK script for me that would be great, because I have no experience using the program.

I'm using Vista Home Premium

Comment: and the OS is ...?

Comment: and what utilities did you try already?

Answer (score 11):

You could give [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) a try.

It is quite powerful, from what I experienced. According to their [key list](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm), your key should be supported:

> - Pause
> - Break -- Since this is
>     synonymous with Pause, use ^CtrlBreak
>     in hotkeys instead of ^Pause or
>     ^Break.

If it has a special code, you can also retrieve it, following instructions on the same page.

The instruction to remap <kbd>F12</kbd> to <kbd>Pause</kbd> is simply like this:

```
F12::Pause
```

Comment: I use AHK to map pause/break to pause/play!

Comment: AHK is a must for every windows user

Answer (score 5):

I used [Sharpkeys](http://www.randyrants.com/2008/12/sharpkeys_30.html) to swap places my Win and LCtrl buttons. (For using same hotkeys for Mac and Win) Actually it can map any key to any another key.

Comment: +1 for not having to have a tool run in the background 24/7.

Comment: I love it too. I just tried, and it worked great, minus the part about not supporting the pause/break key, which I looked up on the forums

Comment: @D'Arvit `Pause/Break`  generate 4 byte sequence that can't be remapped with registry hack.

Comment: I was able to remap the missing BREAK key on the Acer Nitro 5 to the Nitro key using E0_75 -> E0_46. This also works for CTRL+ALT+BREAK for RDP full screen.

Answer (score 0):

[`xmodmap`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/xmodmap/) can remap any key that generates a recognizable scan code.

Comment: The question is tagged windows vista

Comment: @Michael: It wasn't when I answered.

Answer (score 0):

For a mainframe screen I needed the pause/break key, but it's not available on a Dell Inspiron 1464 model.

- For <kbd>Pause</kbd> use <kbd>Fn</kbd> with <kbd>Ins</kbd>
- For <kbd>Break</kbd> use <kbd>Fn</kbd> with <kbd>Delete</kbd>

No need to remap any keys.